# Why can't I attach USB devices to a Windows Virtual PC host?

Tags: windows-7, usb, microsoft-virtual-pc, windows-98

I'm trying to run a Windows 98 program in a Windows 98 virtual machine in Windows Virtual PC that requires a USB device (more specifically LEGO Mindstorms Robotics Invention System 2.0 and its USB IR tower that is used to connect with the RCX) and that does not run properly on NT-based computers (the program's readme states that it is "not designed to run on Windows NT/2000"). I know that Windows Virtual PC can redirect USB devices to virtual guests. However, the only menus that I see in the VM window are Action and Tools. The USB menu which shows up in Windows XP Mode that allows me to redirect USB devices does not show up in Windows 98. Why does it not show up?

Comment: You probably need to install the USB/Mass storage drivers for Windows 98, as some versions don't come with all of the drivers needed to run the device. Source: http://www.technical-assistance.co.uk/kb/usbmsd98.php

Comment: Have you tried either VMWare Workstation or Virtaulbox?

Comment: Instead of messing around with Windows 98, have you seen/tried this yet? [Using LEGO Mindstorms RIS (RCX) KIT with Windows7](http://www.mindstormsrobots.com/lego-minstorms/lego-mindstorms-ris-windows7/)

Comment: @techie007 The nice thing is, Windows Virtual PC supports *serial port* redirection, so I can turn my USB-to-serial adapter and use it as a physical serial port for the virtual machine and hook up a serial tower (if I have one) and use it in Windows 98. However, that's not needed as my copy of Windows 7 is 32-bit (though I do have Windows Server 2012 R2 if I need 64-bit).

Comment: @techie007 That didn't work for me. I installed both files, but I receive a critical error message when I try to use the software when it tries to detect my USB tower.